# Customize web deployment package in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, msdeploy, web-deployment

I have a WCF DataService build in VS 2010, targetting .Net 4.0. This all works fine. I've created a deployment package and have the application deployed to a web server using MSDeploy and a zip file. When I set up an automated build on a TFS Build Agent the contents of the deployment package changed. I no longer get the strong named assemblies in my deployment package. These excluded assemblies are projects within the solution and are built on the Build Server.

I don't see a lot of configuration options for the deployment package, but I would like to know why the build server creates a different package than my workstation, using the same settings.

I am using "Only files needed to run this application", I have ticked "Exclude generated debug symbols" and "Exclude files from App_Data folder". I _do_not_ include database packages. I *do* create a zip file (which is missing the strong named assemblies)

Thanks for any information you may have explaining why this occurs. Then maybe I can solve the problem.

Beezler

On the build server I've ungaced the assemblies I was concerned about and that got my deployment package to the state I want it. So it appears the deployment package does not include the GACed assemblies, which is a good thing. I would still like to know how to override this behavior on certain referenced assemblies.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a DLL files for a GAC assembly do the following:

- In your project, expand the "References" folder
- right-click on the reference you want to include the DLL and click "properties" to bring up the properties pane
- set "Copy Local" to "True"

That's it!  When publishing your project, it will include the DLL in the bin folder for that reference!